# Duplicate functions inside a WP_Query

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a WP_Query that shows a list of posts. Pretty standard, however, within that I'm call multiple instances of functions like the_title(); for use in a popup modal that is supposed to display the post that was clicked on, but instead just shows the first one in the loop again.

```
<?php
   $members = new WP_Query( 'post_type=member' );
   if ( $members->have_posts() ) :
   while ( $members->have_posts() ) : $members->the_post();

   // get the src of the post thumbnail
   $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full', false, '' ); 
   $thumbnailSrc = $src[0];  
   ?>

        <div class="col-sm-3 member">
          <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumbnailSrc; ?>&h=250&w=250&zc=1q=100" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#memberModal">
          <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
          <p><?php the_field('member_title'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="memberModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumbnailSrc; ?>&h=300&w=650&zc=1q=100" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_field('member_title'); ?></p>
                <p class="lead"><?php the_field('member_introduction'); ?></p>
                <?php the_field('member_description'); ?>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

        <?php endwhile; else:
          echo '<p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>';
          endif;
        ?>
```

In the example above, a div.member is created for each post. But then the div.modal only shows the first post.

In a way, I'm trying to create one of these (div.member + div.modal) for each post.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a visual representation. The loop spits out the four 'members' in the post_type with the data for each one.

http://img42.com/k2Cdx

But no matter which one I click on, the modal just fetches the data from the first post.

http://img42.com/Pjq9P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is creating multiple modals all with the same classes and IDs. When you click on the link to display the modal, the JS will only get the first item in the DOM. I suggest you create a loop counter to increment your IDs.

Before the while loop starts ->

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
```

Just inside the while loop ->

```
<?php $count++; ?>
```

Then for your ID ->

```
<div class="modal fade" id="memberModal<?php echo $count; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

This would increment the IDs which you can then target with jQuery. If you want this to function correctly, you're going to have to count the number of entries and then loop in jQuery as well or you could localize the script and output the variables to your JS.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help!

As an extra note I had to echo the $count on the data-target attribute as well.

Answer (score 0):

the_title() should need any type of argument for identifying current iterating post.
You're not specifying post_id neither post object or any global value which could be used by the_title().

For example you could pass argument **$post->ID** just like you do in **get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)**

Can I ask you something? Where are you setting **$post** var?
I suposse you want to do it inside *while* loop but I can't see where it's been done

Maybe you need something like

```
$post = $members->the_post();
```

In your *while* loop first line...

Comment: My PHP knowledge is not strong. I didn't know that you had to set the $post variable. I've tried setting the $post variable as you suggested , but the loop only echoes out two posts.

I've also tried setting the `global $post` inside (and outside) the loop to access the data from the current post, but it just does the same thing as my original code.

Is there a way to create a variable for each post, and then call that variable multiple times in the loop?

Tried `$member_name = the_title();` and then called it later twice, but it just fetched the first again.

Appreciate your help